# How to configure a vpn or tunnel using shared public ip provided by my isp

Tags: networking, router, ssh, vpn, lan

I have a LAN in my house and it is connected to a modem/router. I have some monitoring services running in a server outside my house. I need to contact my PC from the monitoring services and send some data. The problem is that my ISP shares my public IP with other costumers. I have internet access in my LAN but i can't connect to any incoming connections inside my LAN because the ISP NAT does not map my router in any specific port. Is there a way to connect my LAN and my outside server via a VPN or something ?.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your solution of using a VPN is the answer - but you will need to find a provider that will give you a valid endpoint on the VPN.  They do exist - I googled vpn static IP and came up with a few.

Thinking about it a bit more, if you have the skills, you could rent an LEB (Low End Box = Low end Virtual Server ), and configure that as an endpoint for your VPN, then either have 2 VPN connections to that LEB so your machines can see each other or port-forward from the VPN to your known RFC1918 IP address directly - this might be a cheaper solution.

Comment: Rereading my answer, it only answers half the question.  You would simply set up a VPN to your VPN provider - and, provided that provider offers a static IP address, that address will be routed to your computer.  You need to be a bit careful and run a firewall as you can't rely on the protections offered by your router [ as the static IP address bypasses those]